# Scikit-learn - what happens when the contents of a variable gets too large to store in memory?

Tags: variables, memory, memory-management, scikit-learn

In machine learning, it is very common to work with large data. From what I know, variables are loaded into main memory when they get used because the CPU can directly access main memory. I guess this question doesn't have to be specific to Scikit-learn but this is just to give a specific example. I am working with text data represented as bag-of-words using a list. I know that you can use Scipy to make storing the bag-of-words more efficient. But I am curious as to what will happen when the variable gets too large to store in memory.

From a programmer's perspective, is it alright to assume that everything will still work as usual wherein we can think of the variable as stored 'virtually' in memory? (Virtually here means that a part of the variable is stored on the disk and main memory but we can treat it as a black box and let the operating system handle the switching from disk to main memory and vice versa.)

Comment: Your system will start to *trash* and it will not react to much anymore. Furthermore your cpu-usage approaches 0% as hdd-based access is too slow to generate enough work for your cpu. This basically means: there is no more progress (orders of magnitudes slower). And your mentioning of scipy to make things more efficient is basically only the choice: dense vs. sparse data (not much else you can do, except for using the right types).

Comment: As far as I know and I've seen, you can't really be certain of this behavior, meaning it depends on many things, like the swapping settings and how everything is handled by the os. You usually make use of techniques like `lazy loading` and generators (in python) to ensure that you won't run out of memory. Frameworks like Apache Spark can handle these memory concerns under the hood very well.

Comment: Spark and co. might work on different assumptions. Using sklearn, the core assumption is: you got enough memory and therefore if not, the OS try to work on it (failing at some time). Of course you can implement this get-partial-data, work, repeat yourself  (within sklearn, e.g. all the partial_fit compatible algorithms) and it might work fine. But this time: it's problem-driven manual memory-management somehow. Expect failure, when the OS needs to do this for you (as the OS does not know your algorithms = access-patterns).

Comment: @sascha +1 "Expect failure, when the OS need to do this for you." Exactly. In other words, make sure you have enough memory - or change tools and process.

Comment: python itself will lead to a `memory error` in cases where calculated sizes of objects exceed free memory size. I experience that with numpy, when I try to create huge empty arrays.

Comment: @Dschoni I think it's more complex than that. While i observed this behaviour a lot of times, i also have much more experience with trashing in numpy and sklearn-based code (no memory error). Sadly i can't give any rules what is to be expected in which case (except for simple cases, like allocating a huge np-array like ```np.ones(range(100))```).

Comment: @sascha: I expect, in cases, where the calculated size is not known in advance, it results in trashing rather than a memory error. Simple example where my system trashes is creating a list and appending numbers. Allocating a huge np array doesn't even take memory if the calculated size exceeds it.

Comment: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/python-memory-management.html for reference

Comment: @Dschoni This is more of a hardware question. Why is it not possible to just store the whole variable on the disk and let the CPU operate on it? This might take a long explanation so a link would be fine :)

Comment: @Patrick this IS somehow possible. At least with memory mapping. I know, that numpy can do that, but unless you explicitly specify it will not do it.

Comment: @Dschoni Interesting. Will have a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html